# Call an expensive function periodically inside a loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, periodicity, periodic-processing

I call a computationally expensive function inside a loop:

```
for( int j = 0; j < Max; ++j ) {

    // ...

    processQueuedEvents(); // Computationally expensive call

    // ...

}
```

However, I don't need to run the expensive function on every single loop iteration, so I want to call it **periodically**:

```
for( int j = 0; j < Max; ++j ) {

    // ...

    if ( /* The condition I'm talking about */ ) 
        processQueuedEvents(); // Computationally expensive call

    // ...

}
```

At this point, I need to develop a proper condition for my periodic call. The condition should correlate to `Max`, I mean, if `Max` is **larger**, the expensive call is **less**-frequent and if `Max` is **smaller** the expensive call is **more**-frequent.

Does anybody have any suggestions or hints? For some reason, I have a hard time coming up with a proper condition.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want a fixed number of calls across the whole loop, i.e. check whether `j >= Max / numberOfCalls` (potential off-by-one error here).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! I'm going to try it

Comment: `j % period == 0`, and period should increase as Max increases, e.g. `j % (Max / numberOfCalls) == 0`.

Comment: @felix Right! That's the relationship :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide enough details about the increment function you want to use. If you are considering a liner one you can reason with factors of 10 in the following manner:

- `0 <= Max < 10` - invoke the expensive call each execution of the loop.
- `10 <= Max < 100` - invoke the expensive call each `10-th (j % 10 == 0)` execution of the loop.
- `100 <= Max < 1000` - invoke the expensive call each `100-th (j % 100 == 0)` execution of the loop.

and so on.